# Add Hashmap array to Listview

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to Android programming and I am having tremendous trouble with this simple task.

I have a ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

And I want to add each key/value pair to a ListView.

How do I add them to the ListView?  I have seen countless explanations of using the adapter online but they all use variables I know nothing about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your own adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private HashMap<String, String> map;

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity, HashMap<String, String> map) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return map.size();
    }    

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item,
                    null);
        }

            // Recommended to use a list as the dataset passed in the constructor.
            // Otherwise not sure how you going to map a position to an index in the dataset.
            String key = // get a key from the HashMap above
            String value = map.get(key);

            TextView keyView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_key);
            keyView.setText(key);

            TextView valueView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_value);
            valueView .setText(value);

        return convertView;
    }    
}
```

Then, pass it into your ListView setAdapter method:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, map);
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Sample layout/my_list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android:http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_key"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is R.layout.my_list_item? I only have a listview.

Comment: I'm also not sure how to populate the view with my items.

Comment: You can create your own custom layout for how you want a row to look like. That is R.layout.my_list_item.

Comment: Updated answer to include sample layout file and sample code. Hope this helps you :)